# need to search the pattern and print its next value

Tags: linux, shell, awk

**Query:** I have file with multiple line with below text,
need to fetch 2 entry from each line,  APP_ID:686 & APP_SUBSC_ID:68601 fields are not constant its random. Need to search the pattern and print next value.

**Question:** How can it be done ?

**Input file**

```
1.**8340411087390720000**     68601 CSS:css|unidades_promotion:NA|stopc:False|USER-AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1;Safari/537.36|CONTENT_ID:|cmpSrc:TrafficCompany_MK|omrevposition:|unidades:999999|randomAmtFlag:false|**APP_ID:686**|CIRCLE_ID:1|PACK_NAME:CVAS_44869_SUB|network-type:WIFI|cmpId:Spain_Movistar_Tinder_TrafficCompany|opr:Telefonica-CVAS|**APP_SUBSC_ID:68601**|ctry:ES|ctid:m7RZCi6ANPG2rIMFIIhOCJR5qjLad6o95JVBnr2V8Sc|bypasslimit:|svc:19|APP_NAME:TINDER|sid:m7RZCi6ANPG2rIMFIIhOCJR5qjLad6o95JVBnr2V8Sc|
```

**Code**

```
awk -f "|" '{ for (x=1; x<NF; x++ ) { if ($x == "APP_SUBSC_ID:") {x=x+1; printf("%s\n", $x); break}}}'
```

**Output required:**

```
APP_ID:686 APP_SUBSC_ID:68601
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do edit your question with better samples of input and expected output, also add your tried code(which is highly encouraged on SO), thank you.

Comment: edited the question is input and output required. i have tired with awk and for loop .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/APP_ID:[0-9]+/){
  id=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/APP_SUBSC_ID:[0-9]+/){
  print (id?id:"No id"),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  id=""
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/APP_ID:[0-9]+/){           ##using match function to match APP_ID: digits here.
  id=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)       ##Creating id variable which has matched regex value as shown above.
}
match($0,/APP_SUBSC_ID:[0-9]+/){     ##Using match function to match APP_SUBSC_ID: digits here.
  print (id?id:"No id"),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ##Printing id or no_id(in case its not found) and value of matched sub string.
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

As per OP's comment for using one liner use:

`awk 'match($0,/APP_ID:[0-9]+/){id=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} match($0,/APP_SUBSC_ID:[0-9]+/){print (id?id:"No id"),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file`

Comment: @BhavanaR, Hey Bhavana, this is a tested code, if you want to try in oneliner then try something like `awk 'match($0,/APP_ID:[0-9]+/){id=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} match($0,/APP_SUBSC_ID:[0-9]+/){print id,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file` once and let me know then?

Comment: + awk '
match($0,/APP_ID:[0-9]+/){
  id=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/APP_SUBSC_ID:[0-9]+/){
  print (id?id:"No id"),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  id=""
}' search.txt
APP_ID:686 APP_SUBSC_ID:68601

Comment: I got the expected output from both code given . Thanks for the quick response . @Ravinder

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK`. Let `file.txt` content be:

```
1.**8340411087390720000**     68601 CSS:css|unidades_promotion:NA|stopc:False|USER-AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1;Safari/537.36|CONTENT_ID:|cmpSrc:TrafficCompany_MK|omrevposition:|unidades:999999|randomAmtFlag:false|**APP_ID:686**|CIRCLE_ID:1|PACK_NAME:CVAS_44869_SUB|network-type:WIFI|cmpId:Spain_Movistar_Tinder_TrafficCompany|opr:Telefonica-CVAS|**APP_SUBSC_ID:68601**|ctry:ES|ctid:m7RZCi6ANPG2rIMFIIhOCJR5qjLad6o95JVBnr2V8Sc|bypasslimit:|svc:19|APP_NAME:TINDER|sid:m7RZCi6ANPG2rIMFIIhOCJR5qjLad6o95JVBnr2V8Sc|
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="(APP_ID:[0-9]+)|(APP_SUBSC_ID:[0-9]+)"}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
APP_ID:686 APP_SUBSC_ID:68601
```

Explanation: I specified `FPAT` i.e. *field pattern*, therefore instructing to treat matching elements of line as fields: (`APP_ID:` followed by one or more digits) or (`APP_SUBSC_ID:` followed by one or more digits). Then I need to do something so `AWK` would rebuilt line therefore I do `$1=$1` (without it `print` would print whole unaltered line)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*